# How to JUnit4-test Spring's el-Expressions on mocked request?

Tags: java, spring, junit4, easymock

This is what i have but the Assert always thorws a AsserationException:

```
@Configuration
public class Config
  @Bean
  public HttpServletRequest request(){
     HttpServleRequest mock = EasyMock.createMock(HttpServletRequest.class);
     EasyMock.expect(mock.getParameter("test")).andReturn("123").anyTimes();
     EasyMock.replay(mock);
     return mock;
  }

  @Bean
  MySerivce service(){
    return new MyService();
  }

  @Bean
  public ApplicationContextProvider context(){
    return new ApplicationContextProvider();
  }
}
```

This is the Service `MyService.java`:

```
public class MyService{
  public void assertHasRequest(@Value("#{request}") HttpServletRequest request)){
    assert request != null;
  }
}
```

The test: `TestExpressions.java`:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClasssRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=Config.class)
public class TestExpressions {

  @Autowired
  MyService service;

  @Test
  public void testService(){
    service.assertHasRequest(null);
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not massively sure what you're trying to get to, but it looks neat. A couple of potential issues to my eye: 1) The mock isn't in replay mode when it's returned from the 'request()' method. I think you want to call 'EasyMock.replay(mock);' before returning. 2) The assert statement is checking the provided value is not null, but you call it directly with null as the parameter. Of course it throws an assertion error. Surely you want to inject the request object and call the method with that?

Comment: @DanTemple 1) Sounds legit but nothing changed, i add this to the Question. 2) Yes.

Comment: Cool, well then you can just follow the same process as you have for service in the test class I think. So have a variable called request of type HttpServletRequest and then annotate it @Autowired. Then you can just pass it to the 'assertHasRequest(request)' method where you have null currently.

Comment: @DanTemple I do this in a different Test, i like to test `@Value` not `@Autowire`.

Comment: Well I'm not sure if that's possible, but taking a look at [this example I found online](https://gist.github.com/danlangford/3418696) I think you want to mark the `MyService` class with `@Component` and then put `@ComponentScan` at the top of your config class too. Although, having said that I have seen some blog posts claiming this type of thing isn't possible.

Comment: @DanTemple You can either 1) use a `@Bean` in a class with `@Configuration` or 2) use @ComponentScan with @Component or 3) use the xml-configuration-style. Anyways, they are deployed to the Spring Context.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Pass null as an argument in `assertHasRequest` and expect Spring to overcome that null and inject something else?

Comment: My Spring Version is 3.2

Comment: @PeterRader `@Value` is not meant to be used like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Value` is not meant to be used like that. Its main purpose is to provide a way of specifying a default value for an injected field, when **autowiring** happens. This is important to mention, because you seem to want to use `@Value` when a method is being called from your code, whereas when you call that method autowiring already happened and you cannot change with anything the already autowired field using `@Value`. `@Value` is used once at instance creation time.

The simplest way of using `@Value` with something around what you need is like this:

```
public class MyService {

   @Value("#{request}")
   private HttpServletRequest request;

   public void assertHasRequest() {// no parameters here because they don't act on local field this.request
       assertNotNull(this.request);
   }
}
```

In the code above, when Spring creates the MyService instance specified in your `Config` class, it will detect the use of `@Value` and when `MyService` is created (way before you get to call `assertHasRequest()`) it will inject the `request` instance it finds.

Let me give you another example:

```
public class MyService {

    private HttpServletRequest request;

    public void assertHasRequest() {
        assertNotNull(this.request);
    }

    @Value("#{request}")
    private void initialize(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("initializing request");
        this.request = request;
    }
}
```

In this code, `@Value` is placed on a method `initialize()`. This method is automatically being called by Spring container when the `MyService` instance is created, **once**. It's like an initialization method with the purpose of setting the field `request`. You can call that method from your code, if you want, but it won't work. `@Value` has a meaning for Spring to know what to do after it created the bean instance.

For `@Value` placed on a parameter of a method or constructor, one needs to use `@Autowired`:

```
public class MyService {

    private HttpServletRequest request;

    public void assertHasRequest() {
        assertNotNull(this.request);
    }

    @Autowired
    private void initialize(@Value("#{request}") HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("initializing request: " + request);
        this.request = request;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, is there any alternate to `@Value` without using custom AOP injecting a value?

Comment: Nop. I have seen your code so far and asked what you are trying to do, but I have the feeling things are still not clear, for both of us. Your code shows `HttpServletRequest` but anything else is not proving you want this tested in a web environment. If you are, though, take a look at [this testing class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/test/java/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/ExpressionValueMethodArgumentResolverTests.java) from Spring itself.

Comment: My original plan was to write a new Test like `void assertTestParameterIs123(@Value("${request.getParameter('test')}") String test)` on the `@Service`-Class. But i know now - without a custom AOP-Pointcut - it is hopeless.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you can't use the `@Value` annotation directly on a method parameter in such a way that it would be able to replace an argument with a default, in case null is provided.

In your case the `@Value` annotation is used together with [AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.beans/3.0.5/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java) and this processor is not monitoring for `@Value` annotations on level of method arguments.

You can instead place the `@Value` on method level, which will make Spring to inject the `HttpServletRequest` bean from context, but it won't be doing so on every request:

```
public class MyService {

    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Value("#{request}")
    public void assertHasRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (request != null) {
            this.request = request;
        }
        assert this.request != null;
    }

}
```

The config class:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public HttpServletRequest request() {
        HttpServletRequest mock = EasyMock.createMock(HttpServletRequest.class);
        EasyMock.expect(mock.getParameter("test")).andReturn("123").anyTimes();
        EasyMock.replay(mock);
        return mock;
    }

    @Bean
    MyService service() {
        return new MyService();
    }

}
```

Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=Config.class)
public class TestExpressions {

    @Autowired
    MyService service;

    @Test
    public void testService(){
        service.assertHasRequest(null);
    }
}
```

Using the `@Value` inside Spring MVC controllers will behave differently.

Comment: My test Failed, did you tried it yourself with success?

Comment: Yes I did, I'll send you my complete code later today.

Comment: Hey the junit/spring version may do the trick. Can you tell me the version-numbers?

Comment: It should be Spring 4.

Comment: I use 3.2, looks like this is the problem.

Comment: Seems to work well with 3.2.8 as well for me. My complete code is updated in the answer.

Comment: Sorry, as Andrei sais: `assertHasRequest` is called before `testService` is called, so the JUnit-Test this way is inconclusive. I tested it and i can confirm Andrei's point, can you confirm this too?

Comment: Yes, the assertHasRequest is called exactly once before the testService - that's what I meant with "but it won't be doing so on every request" in the answer above.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't really test anything much. If your goal is to inject current HttpServletRequest objects, you should go with Spring MVC which has extensive capabilities in doing so. If you're trying to initialize a Spring bean with a reference to another bean, autowiring or using @Value directly on a field or field's setter will work just fine. If you want to test whether the autowiring/@Value worked, just test it by checking that the field's getter returns a value.